# Don't repeat exponent in \SIrange

Tags: siunitx, sirange

This

```
\SIrange{2e12}{5e12}{\meter}
```

renders as

[image]

I would like to not repeat the exponent, i.e.

```
(2-5)x10^12 m
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fix the exponent and adjust a  few other settings

```
\SIrange[scientific-notation = fixed, range-units = brackets, fixed-exponent = 12]%
{2e12}{5e12}{\metre}
```

Probably in a 'real' case some of these will be set globally (`\sisetup`).

Comment: How can I do this with just a `\numrange` ?

Answer (score 1):

In the [manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/siunitx/0), under "ranges", it explains how you can set this in the `sisetup`:

```
\sisetup{
    range-exponents = individual / combine-bracket / combine
}
```

`individual` is the default, it will repeat the exponent. Both `combine-bracket` and `combine` will not, with the difference being if brackets are included.